# Transistor Noise A Concern In Emitter Follower

Tags: audio, bjt, noise, emitter-follower

I'm looking at using a high voltage BJT as an emitter follower in a high voltage tube audio application (guitar amp). Unfortunately in the range of 200V, most BJTs are marketed as switching transistors and have no noise specs etc. Also I'm aware transistors in this range have a low beta, that's fine, I'm looking to still have some source loading.

My assumption is due to a large input voltage, any noise that the transistor would add to the circuit is effectively negligible. That being said, I am not familiar with understanding noise figures in dB vs affect on something like an emitter follower...

**Question:** In general for emitter followers, with a *typical* ~100mV to ~10V AC signal bounded in the audio frequency realm, Does the quality of transistor matter?

Comment: *My assumption is due to a large input voltage, any noise that the transistor would add to the circuit is effectively negligible.* So, since tubes generally need a high voltage, their noise can be ignored as well? How about considering that although the **DC biasing voltage** needs to be high, that doesn't mean that the **signal voltage** is high as well. And what matters is the signal/noise ratio. A transistor biased at Vce = 200 V can still add noise to a signal when the signal is small.

Comment: If you just want level shifting, use a gas_discharge tube such as OB2.